# What tools are available for testing client/server software in various network topologies?

Tags: tools, sockets

For testing a client/server platform that communicates over TCP/IP, is there a tool available to mimic various types of interposed network component, such a firewall with NAT or a SOCKS5 server.

Essentially, I want to have this configuration:

client <-> proxy <-> server

I want to be able to specify what type of proxy to mimic and I don't want to install a bunch of heavy or expensive proxy servers.

A bonus would be for the proxy to include traffic shaping features.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Ixia](http://www.ixiacom.com/) and/or [Shunra](http://www.shunra.com/).  Neither are particularly cheap, but both are certainly capable of this.

A Linux box would also work for such a situation.

If you're after a free packet generator, you could try [Ostinato](http://code.google.com/p/ostinato/) - comes with a GUI as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what all kinds of proxies you would like to mimic, but to me it sounds like any linux box could be your solution and serve running those programs. If you want more complicated network topologies or just don't have even the one machine to add between the client and server, you can probably run all the components in virtual machines using for example VirtualBox.