# Online test platform for sockets

Tags: sockets

Does anyone know of a website that can accept a TCP/IP socket connection and show data sent to it? There are many sites that can display HTTP transactions and many installable programs that can do this, but I haven't been able to find an online version.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this online tool for socket testing earlier. Can you have a look at http://demos.kaazing.com/echo/?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be on your local network? If so, you can check out the various example programs at [Rosetta](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Echo_server) and run whatever language you are most comfortable with. Tweak it to the port of your choice, and perhaps instead of echoing, have it output the data to a file or local terminal if you want a better way to access the data.

Comment: Unfortunately it can't be the local network as it's a GPRS module that I'm testing. I could get it to 'talk' to my gateway but I'm sure it wouldn't do anything sensible with a raw socket connection :-)

Comment: I suppose you could put it external, but you'd have to be aware that anyone could reach it then. But that's exactly what you want, I think.

Comment: Yes, that wouldn't be a concern - I suppose if it did exist it would be a very vulnerable site!              Portquiz [link](http://portquiz.net/)   is close to what I'm looking for - I can establish a connection to it.

Comment: but why won't you build a network in your lab to simulate the internet? add a few routers, define the routing rules and build a very simple application to accept your calls

Comment: I'm offsite (long story.. I'm slightly incapacitated!) so only have a home network. That has a Sky router, which I could 'talk' to but I'm not sure how I would then get it to forward traffic to a local PC? I can open it up for incoming connections.. not sure what to do then. A web/app company is doing the server side .. but they are not ready yet so was trying to do some testing independent of them.

Comment: May relate to http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/5499/8992